# Range of electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

I was reading [this article](http://www.lightreading.in/document.asp?doc_id=226833&site=lrindia&). There is a statement   "It is a well-known fact that the telecom towers mounted with antennas in the lower frequency bands can cover far greater areas than those using the 1800 frequency bands." Is this accurate/wrong/a simplified version.  One point which made me think that it is wrong is the fact that Satellite TV uses high frequency bands for communication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of cellular radio communication the statement that the lower frequencies propagate further is correct.  The frequency dependence is empirically illustrated in the [Hata formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COST_Hata_model) for propagation in urban areas.  This formula predicts the path loss (the attenuation in decibels) from the transmitter to the receive position.  It actually gives the path loss averaged over an area of the order of maybe a hundred meters.

A principal contributor to the frequency dependence in urban areas is the diffraction loss caused by propagation over/past buildings.  See this [review article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2187).

The other contributor to path loss - the free space loss - is common to both the cellular and satellite cases.  The satellite, however, using line-of-sight communication does not have the diffraction component in the calculation.